# New list items shadowing previous items due to negative margin

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a step indicator which I implemented as a list:

```
<ol>
    <li>Step 1</li>
    <li class="active">Step 2</li>
    <li>Step 3</li>
</ol>
```

Each list element has a rounded edge to it's right in order to indicate progress, so I have the following CSS:

```
li{
  display: block; background-color: white; width: 33%; border: 1px solid #ddd; text-indent: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
```

My problem is that later elements are shadowing the earlier, thus the rounded edge are hidden. I've tried to set a decreasing z-index for each element, but it doesn't work (besides I couldn't use this solution anyway). I acheive the desired presentation by changing to `float:right` but that renders the list items in descending order...

Check this jsfiddle for details: http://jsfiddle.net/fMRbr/

Comment: why don't you use `float: right` and just change the order of steps in your markup? http://jsfiddle.net/fMRbr/1/

Comment: @ZoltanToth: That would make no sense if anything that doesn't understand CSS ever sees it. Don't do things like that; content should be useful even without styling.

Comment: I could do that, but I think it would be a little awkward. I was hoping for a better way to achieve this, being better semantically.

Comment: Do you *want* the list items to overlap?  It's unclear whether that's your intended result.  The CSS you provided can easily be updated to provide a non-overlapping solution, but that might not be what you want.

Comment: I want them to overlap, but I want to turn the direction of how the elements are stacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:before`

```css
li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    background-color: white;
    text-indent: 40px;
    
    position: relative;
}

li.active{
 background-color: red;   
}

li:before{
    content: '';
    width: 15px;
    height: 19px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -3px;
}

li.afteractive:before {
    content: '';
    width: 15px;
    height: 19px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f00;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -3px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="active">Step 1</li>
  <li class="afteractive">Step 2</li>
  <li>Step 3</li>
</ol>

<br /><br />

<ol>
  <li>Step 1</li>
  <li class="active">Step 2</li>
  <li class="afteractive">Step 3</li>
</ol>

<br /><br />

<ol>
  <li>Step 1</li>
  <li>Step 2</li>
  <li class="active">Step 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea! Although it doesn't seem to work between two white elements..?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `border-radius` and negative `margin` values, have you considered a  Tbackground image at the top right of each `<li>` which looks like this:

[image: Greather than symbol]

The active (red) `<li>` would have a similar background but colored red. The result should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: The finaly solution will probably be based on a right aligned background image, but I also need to solve the line at the top and at the bottom, which shouldn't go all the way to the edge.

Answer (score 0):

Add a span tag to your li's with `display: inline-block` so they automatically grow to the right width:

**html**

```
<ol>
  <li><span>Step 1</span></li>
  <li class="active"><span>Step 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Step 3</span></li>
</ol>
```

**css**

```
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
  background-color: white;
  text-indent: 40px;
}
li.active {
}

li.active span {
  background-color: red;
}
li span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

See a jsfiddle of this solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/HYQSJ/

Comment: But I do need the items to overlap, only in the other direction, so that the result would be like @NobRuked's image.